# Pandas stock regression chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I would like to create a simple linear regression chart just like in excel. With the shortest way possible.

Which is the easiest way to to plot a stock returns chart with a regression line using the pandas .plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be pretty simple with [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.abline_plot.html#statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.abline_plot)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
mod = sm.OLS.from_formula('y ~ x', data=df)  # y and x are column names in the DataFrame
res = mod.fit()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sm.graphics.abline_plot(model_results=res, ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', ax=ax)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `model_results=res` (not `model_results=mod`) in your `sm.graphics.abline_plot()` call?

Comment: Yeah, I thought I fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an error and it goes like this:     raise ValueError('Invalid chart type given %s' % kind)
ValueError: Invalid chart type given scatter

Comment: Thanks for your answer . To restate my question: Hypothetically i want to plot a chart with the linear regression of the pct change of the SP500. How do i do that?

Comment: Get the data, calculate the percent change with `pct_change` (or the log difference with np.log(df.diff())`. Your `x` in this case will just be the index. There may be some problems with using dates as the `x` variable, so you might just want to make a dummy column with `(range(len(df))`